# UITextField focus

Tags: iphone, textinput

How can I programmatically assign focus to a specific UITextField in a view? I have several fields and on view display, I'd like to put the cursor on a specific field, not the first one at top.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Try doing this in `viewWillAppear:`

```
[desiredField becomeFirstResponder];
```

By making the field the first responder, it have focus and the keyboard will be displayed.

Comment: Hi, are you sure it works on viewWillAppear? I tried it, it didn't work. Instead I put it on viewDidLoad, and it works.

Comment: IMHO, it's best to put this in `viewDidAppear`. The visual effect is nicer.

Comment: This is the code in Swift for those who need it. `desiredField.becomeFirstResponder()`

Comment: @MickeyCheong Don't forget to call `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` inside of the overridden viewDidAppear. It won't work without it.

Answer (score 5):

Set the first responder for your view to be the text field.  This can be done in IB.

Answer (score 3):

In swift:

```
desiredField.becomeFirstResponder()
```