# Select a new textbox from code iPhone dev

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITextField focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014999/uitextfield-focus)

the title may be a bit confusing.. couldn't figure out how to word it right. My question is simple, when the view loads I want a textbox to be selected for editing. Similar the to the next in the iPhone safari textbox editing.

Comment: try [myTextBox becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014999/uitextfield-focus

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm really sorry for the silly question, I'm still pretty new to the iPhone SDK and the API's provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for it, try the below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```