# UITextField input every time new iteration

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm  new to Objective-C and Xcode, and I have one problem, I tried looking in the Internet, but didn't find anything. 
I have "game" and there I have a screen with two text fields, button and text view.User inputs integer values and taps the button. After tapping the button some functions(or, methods) are called. Method that is called after typing the button:

```
- (IBAction)okButtonTapped:(id)sender {

int save1=100;
int save2=100;
int save13=1;
int save22=1;

int save12=1;
int save23=1;


while(save13 !=0 && save23 !=0){
[self yourturn:&save1 heap2:&save2];
 save12= save1;
 save22=save2;

 [self compturn:&save12 heap2:&save22];
 save13=save12;
save23=save22;

save1=save13;
save2=save23;
}
```

}

Here some methods are called. And in this methods I use this code to save values from textfields that user inputs:

```
 _heapNumberInt=[self.heapNumberTextField.text intValue];
   _thingsNumberInt=[self.thingsNumberTextField.text intValue];
```

And the question is **how to make users input new values in the textfield  every time when there is new iteration in while loop?**
Sorry for my English(it's not my native language) and for my long question.

All project you can download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2qnm3wtp5wasmk/nim.zip)

P.S. "game" is very simple: there are 2 heaps with 100 things each, user chooses his turn and then he inputs values: heap number(1 or 2 heap) and number of things he wants to take from the heap. Then there is computer's turn. And looser is someone who can't take things from any heap. It is [real game called NIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim).(but here I made only 2 heaps(not 3)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextField focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014999/uitextfield-focus)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to read **Event Handling Guide**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541

About the question, for setting focus to the input you should use

```
[self.heapNumberTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

**UPDATE:**
As I understand you need to:

```
_heapNumberInt = [self.heapNumberTextField.text intValue]; // get value 
[self.heapNumberTextField setEditable:NO]; // disable editing to calculate
[self calculate];
self.heapNumberTextField.text = @""; // clean UITextField
[self.heapNumberTextField setEditable:YES]; // allow editing
[self.heapNumberTextField becomeFirstResponder]; // set focus to the textfield
```

Comment: I meant that now user can input values only once and then this values are used in every iteration, but I need to make it possible for user to input different values after computer's turn